# When I scan a 2D Array, it isn't scanning all the values

Tags: c, helper, view-helpers

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (){
    int i, j, L, C;
    scanf("%d%d", &L, &C);
    char Arrayy[L][C];
    for(i=0;i<L;i++){
         for(j=0;j<C;j++){
            scanf("%c", &Arrayy[i][j]);
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example, I want to scan a character map. "`.`" in the map is water, and "`#`" is land. The map size is 5x5. The input is:

```
 5 5
```

OK, L and C will be 5. Input the `%c` matrix:

```
.....
..#..
.###.
..#..
```

Now the program stops the scan. It was supposed to scan one more time, but it doesn't.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

`%c` reads newlines too.  You should check the return value from `scanf()` in general.  You could always print each character as it is read to ensure you know what is going on.  Use `" %c"` as the format. That will skip white space (such as newlines) and only read non-blank characters, giving you the result you expect.

The first character read by the `%c` is the newline after the second 5, which accounts for why the program stops reading when it does.  You have a newline after the `5`, then 4 lines of 6 characters (5 visible characters plus a newline), giving you 25 characters scanned in total, which is the number it wants.  'Tis interesting: for square matrices of size NxN, you get one newline after the second N, then N-1 lines with N+1 characters on each, so you always stop one line short.

#### Debugging code

Add print statements so you know exactly what is going on as it happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, L, C;
    if (scanf("%d%d", &L, &C) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char Arrayy[L][C];

    for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            if (scanf("%c", &Arrayy[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("[%d,%d] = <%d>\n", i, j, Arrayy[i][j]);
         }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++)
            printf("<%c>", Arrayy[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Working code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, L, C;
    if (scanf("%d%d", &L, &C) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char Arrayy[L][C];

    for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            if (scanf(" %c", &Arrayy[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
                return 1;
            }
         }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++)
            putchar(Arrayy[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is lots of room to improve the error messages, but reporting the error on standard error is important, and reporting some message is important, and exiting with a non-zero (non-success) status is important.